# wsl installation on windows terminal

Tags: windows

I'm trying to install the wsl on my windows 11 terminal but this is the error I get:

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\User> wsl --install
The operation timed out
```

how can I solve this please ?

Comment: Question might get more responses on another stack. Just as it isn't really related to ethereum.